# What is a database-in-one-file supported by hibernate that I can use for a small desktop application?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, sqlite

I'm building this small desktop application for myself, and until now I've been using Hibernate with MySQL, and it works great.
The problem is, I will want to give this application to my friends in the future, and I need some sort of database-in-one-file, something like SQLite, that is supported by Hibernate. Something that you don't need to install in order to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a one-file database that is supported by hibernate via the [project on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). It gives you an option of a file database and also an in-memory one. [Here](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_hibernate) is the info about `Hibernate` integration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/)?  It has since been abandoned, but a fork is maintained [here](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC).